# Laravel relations deep

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using laravel 5.3. I have got `Promotion` belongs to `Device` and `Device` hasMany `emails`. Could anyone give me advice. how can i get in Promotion query all emails connected to device having this promotion?

Currently i'm trying something like this

In Promotion model

```
public function devicesWithEmails()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Device::class)->with('Emails');
}
```

Get query looks like (in Promotion)

```
public function search($data)
{
    $perPage = empty($data['perPage']) ? 10 : $data['perPage'];
    $sortField = empty($data['sortField']) ? 'id' : $data['sortField'];
    $keyword = empty($data['keyword']) ? null : $data['keyword'];

    $promotions = Promotion::whereHas('email', function ($query) use ($keyword) {
        if ( ! empty($keyword)) {
            $query->where('email', 'like', "%{$keyword}%");
        }
    })
    ->orWhere('promo_code', 'like', "%{$keyword}%")
    ->with('devicesWithEmails')
    ->orderBy($sortField)
    ->paginate($perPage);

    return $promotions->toArray();
}
```

Device model

```
public function emails()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Email::class, 'emails_devices');
}
```

Email model

```
public function devices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Device::class, 'emails_devices');
}
```

Promotion model

```
public function device()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Device::class);
}
```

Tables structures are

```
    CREATE TABLE `devices` (
        `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `apptype` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `oid_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `lang` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `referrer` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `app_version` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `mobiledeviceid` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `is_paid` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `status` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `is_internal_user` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `paid_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `paid_date_end` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
    COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `emails` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `client_type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `emails_devices` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `email_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `device_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `emails_devices_email_id_foreign` (`email_id`),
    INDEX `emails_devices_device_id_foreign` (`device_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `emails_devices_device_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `devices` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `emails_devices_email_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`email_id`) REFERENCES `emails` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `promotions` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `batch_name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `promo_code` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `validity` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `device_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `email_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `used_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `promotions_device_id_foreign` (`device_id`),
    INDEX `promotions_email_id_foreign` (`email_id`),
    INDEX `promo_code_index` (`promo_code`),
    CONSTRAINT `promotions_device_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `devices` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `promotions_email_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`email_id`) REFERENCES `emails` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Unfortunately devicesWithEmails always return null.

Comment: What do you have try so far?

Comment: Can you please add some code whatever you try

Comment: I've updated question with code examples. Thanks for attention!

Comment: What was the issue with this query? It's give error or give wrong output? Because using `->with('devicesWithEmails')` you can get all device connected to Promotion

Comment: I'm afraid it returns null

Comment: Are you sure about your searched `$keyword` value is exist in `promo_code` Or `email` field record

Comment: Yes, even simplified query without any conditions returns empty devicesWithEmails

Comment: I'm bit of confusion, What was the relation between `Promotion` and  `Device`? Do you have device id in `Promotion` table?

Comment: Sure, promotion belongs to device

Comment: Can you please share your three table(Promotion,Device,Email)  structure?

Comment: You might be considering `hasManyThrough` for Promotions--->emails

Answer (score 0):

Found simple solution

Just

```
public function search($data)
    {
        $perPage = empty($data['perPage']) ? 10 : $data['perPage'];
        $sortField = empty($data['sortField']) ? 'id' : $data['sortField'];
        $keyword = empty($data['keyword']) ? null : $data['keyword'];

        $promotions = Promotion::whereHas('email', function ($query) use ($keyword) {
            if (!empty($keyword)) {
                $query->where('email', 'like', "%{$keyword}%");
            }
        })
            ->orWhere('promo_code', 'like', "%{$keyword}%")
            ->with('device.emails')
            ->orderBy($sortField)
            ->paginate($perPage);

        return $promotions->toArray();
    }
```